# Copy files from list while keeping subdirectory structure

Tags: bash, file, directory, copy, subdirectory

I have a text file which specifies files that need to be copied:

```
...
b/bamboo/forest/00000456.jpg 
b/bamboo/forest/00000483.jpg
...
c/corridor/00000334.jpg 
c/corridor/00000343.jpg
...
```

However, I would like to copy them while preserving their subdirectory structure. So the result would be:

```
...
newfolder/b/bamboo/forest/00000483.jpg
newfolder/b/bamboo/forest/00000456.jpg 
...
newfolder/c/corridor/00000334.jpg 
newfolder/c/corridor/00000343.jpg 
...
```

I have this `cat /path/to/files.txt | xargs cp -t /dest/path/`. But it just copies everything to one directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cp --parents`:

> `--parents                 -- append source path to target directory`

```
cat /path/to/files | xargs cp --parents -t new_directory
```

If that isn't working for you, then you can take the boring approach and iterate over each file in `/path/to/files.txt` and use `mkdir -p` to make target directories as needed, and then simply copy the file:

```
while read -r file; do
    new_dir="new_directory/$(dirname "$file")"
    #        ^ this is the new directory root
    mkdir -p "$new_dir"
    cp "$file" "$new_dir/$file"
done < <(cat /path/to/files.txt)
```